# XAML: Databinding to window not working after InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to XAML and i'm trying to bind the score property of my window (a backgammon board) to a control.

I was able to get it to work as follows via code behind:

```
public partial class BgBoard : Window
{
    public BgBoard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        _Score = 999;
    }
    private int _Score;
    public string Score { get { return _Score.ToString(); } }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:bgb="clr-namespace:BackgammonBoard"
    xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:BackgammonBoard.Properties"      x:Class="BackgammonBoard.BgBoard"
    Title="Backgammon board" Width="750" Height="500" MinWidth="375" MinHeight="250">    
    <TextBlock x:Name="Player_Score" Text="{Binding Score}"/>
</Window>
```

Next, I wanted to declare the datacontext in XAML instead of code behind. I removed 'Datacontext = This' from code behind and added the following property to my window in XAML :

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Now the score is no longer displayed on my user interface.

However, if I initialize the score in code behind before the call to InitilalizeComponent(), the score is displayed again:

```
public BgBoard()
{
    _Score = 999;
    InitializeComponent(); 
}
```

So my question is, what should i do in XAML to make sure the score is displayed correctly each time it is modified in code behind (and not only when it is initialized before InitializeComponent()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can data bind to a `DependencyProperty` of a `DependencyObject`. The `Window` is a `DependencyObject`, so all you need is a `DependencyProperty`... there's also no need to convert your value into a `string` first. Try this:

```
public static DependencyProperty ScoreProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Score", typeof(int), typeof(BgBoard));

public int Score
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(ScoreProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ScoreProperty, value); }
}

public BgBoard()
{
    Score = 999;
    InitializeComponent(); 
}
```

If you use a `DependencyProperty`, then you can even data bind to it from the XAML file *without setting the `Window.DataContext` at all*:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Player_Score" Text="{Binding Score, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourLocalXamlNamespacePrefix:BgBoard}}}"/>
```

Comment: Tx ! This works. Score is now updated in UI when it is changed in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

the reason you don't see the score is that the property doesn't raise a "change notification" to the UI, you need to implement "[INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" (click the link for explanation)

Comment: Tx ! However, i've tried it by adding a button that changes the score. However, the score's initial value is displayed and not the changed value from the buttonclick.